# Invalid initializer when creating a BITMAP in C

Tags: c, bitmap, screenshot, takesscreenshot

I am trying to make a program that takes a screen shot and saves it, till now it only saves it into a variable (hbCapture). Although the code seems write and I've read several times the documentation, it gives me a invalid initializer error in the creation of the BITMAP.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include <winuser.h>

typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned short u16;
typedef unsigned long u32;
typedef unsigned long long u64;

void getScreen()
{
    u16 screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
    u16 screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);

    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL); //get a desktop dc (NULL for entire screen)
    HDC hDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); //create a dc for capture

    BITMAP hbCapture = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    SelectObject(hDest, hbCapture);

    //Copy screen to bitmap
    BitBlt(hDest, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    //Clean up
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    DeleteDC(hDest);
}
```

This is the header where the function goes

And here is the main.c

```
#include "main.h"

int main()
{
    getScreen();

    return 0;
}
```

--------------------------I've also tryed this and doesn't work--------------------------------------------------------

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include <winuser.h>

typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned short u16;
typedef unsigned long u32;
typedef unsigned long long u64;

void getScreen()
{
    u16 screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
    u16 screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);

    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL); //get a desktop dc (NULL for entire screen)
    HDC hDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); //create a dc for capture

    //test
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    //DeleteDC(hdc);
    //test

    BITMAP bCapture = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    HBITMAP hbCapture = CreateBitmapIndirect(&bCapture);
    SelectObject(hDest, hbCapture);

    //Copy screen to bitmap
    BitBlt(hDest, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    //Clean up
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    DeleteDC(hDest);
}
```

Comment: It should be `HBITMAP hbCapture`, not `BITMAP`. Also you need to cleanup `HBITMAP` handle...

Comment: How could I clean it up? Whitch is the syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See documentation for [CreateCompatibleBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatiblebitmap)

It says the return value is `HBITMAP`, not `BITMAP`

Change to:

```
HBITMAP hbCapture = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

Remove `CreateBitmapIndirect`

You then need to `GetDIBits` to save the bitmap header and pixels in to file.

Also include `DeleteObject(hbCapture)` at the end of the code for cleanup.

Comment: I tryed to do this and although it solved the main error it prompted some errors, all of them where (undefined reference to ...) errors.

Comment: Please see the help section in this website. Read the section about what questions to ask and how.